# Windows dynamic environment value based on date

Tags: windows, environment-variables

is there any way to get custom environment value based on %DATE% value?

I want to set TEMP value to directory with path including current date. When using windows GUI to set this value (System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Values) it's impossible when user or system wide variable is set to %DATE% value: %DATE% isn't evaluated to real value in this way. Unfortunately, I cannot use batch script, it need to be set on system to ensure, that every explorer.exe's child process will have proper value. Maybe weird, but it should be somewhat useful for my need...

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are static and any substitutions would be expanded at the time you set them.

The best you could do would be to write an script/program to change it and then schedule it to run at just after midnight everyday (and start up).

But probably worth pointing out that you can not externally change the environment variables of an already running process.

Comment: Should be enough for me. Thanks a lot for tip :)